# meteorjs image upload / conversion

Tags: meteor

I need to upload a file to meteor, do some image manipulation on it (image conversion if necessary, generate thumbnail  from image ) and then store it in an external  image storage server (s3).  This should be  as fast as possible. 
Do you have any recommendations for a nodejs image processing library ?
also how i can upload a file to meteorjs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up with the following solution:

1) meteor server side route for a custom upload url

```
__meteor_bootstrap__.app.stack.splice (0, 0, {
    route: '/upload',
    handle: function (req,res, next) {
        //handle upload
    }.future ()
});
```

2) use formidable nodejs module inside the function for file upload

Comment: How can I use Formidable nodejs within meteor? Is there a way to install it?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest solution I have found is using FilePicker.io.  It's extremely easy to integrate into your Meteor App and plugs directly into S3.

Answer (score 3):

In my startup (hausor.com) I use https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS and with additional plugins it supports amazon S3 file upload and image scaling/cropping.

Comment: Hi, that look like exactly what I am looking for. Can you please be more specific and explain (post gist) how exactly you do that / what plugins do you use for image scaling/cropping? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Meteor has any support for uploads; perhaps something is planned in the future. In the meantime, I'd either (assuming you can reading the file with a FileReader or something):

a) insert the file into the mongo and then delete it when it is saved to S3

b) save it up to S3 from the client (not sure if there's a "safe" way to do this.. ie without giving away your credentials, but it could be worth exploring).

c) [if you can't use a FileReader] use an iframe or something to POST to an external server you can control that does handle uploads and then communicate with it from the meteor server.

Comment: how can i implement a? I mean  i  need to post data to some meteor url which can interpret it as  binary data. How can i do this ?

Comment: no, what I meant was that you read the data out of the input with a FileReader into a binary blob and then insert that into the mongo db. If you need to post form-data to a URL you are going to need to try option c)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check one of my answer here : [File upload and download using meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727043/file-upload-and-download-using-meteor/41756806#41756806)

I am using busboy for file upload and just use `fs = Npm.require("fs")` for file writing:
Just put these inside busboy:, the save to is the path where you uploaded, simple us APACHE or file hosting and use other port on it..

`file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo))`