# Meteor js api for moblie platforms

Tags: meteor

We have a project where we running Meteor as web front-end and we have PHP+nginx at another port for api calls from mobile platforms.

Meteor and PHP backend are connected to general mongo database.

Meteor doesn't sent to server plain password while authorization and registration and uses Secure Remote Password protocol.

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(user, password, [callback])
```

cannot be used at server

How to create web service that can register/authorize and give tokens to mobile client that can be used for authorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a little tricky as there isn't really good access to POST and GET requests to meteor yet, I think its on the roadmap but you could try this. I borrowed it from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689755/meteorjs-image-upload-conversion)

You could try creating a custom node route for a specific JS request. e.g

```
__meteor_bootstrap__.app.stack.splice (0, 0, {
route: '/checklogin',
handle: function (req,res, next) {
        username = req.param('username') //req contains POST data
        //Check whether the thing is logged in
        //Other stuff..
        res.send({success:false..}});
    }.future ()
});
```

Comment: thank you, I solved problem this way and customized login form for catching plain password from login form for creation of token.

Comment: Sometimes the code does not work unless the `future()` call is removed. What is it for anyway?

Comment: The `future()` is to ensure the code contained runs in its own fiber and return whatever is returned, which is useful if you're using meteor code in there. You might have to `return` something to resolve the future to something though - as described @ https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers