# Image File upload in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor

Trying to find right way to upload a file i.e. user profile pic, and save to server, using MeteorJS.

I tried CollectionFS a few months ago, it refreshed the browser/Meteor web page before the file was saved to the server's file system which ended up showing a broken image link.

I read this post, but I don't want to use S3, and want to make sure I avoid the broken link issue. Maybe I need a callback to tell Meteor NOT to refresh the web page until the image is fully written (and resized) on the server:
[meteorjs image upload / conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689755/meteorjs-image-upload-conversion)

Comment: In regards to your issue about the incorrect image being displayed, you could write the image URL to a Meteor Collection once the upload is complete.

Have the image `src` be dependent on the meteor collection, then the image will update its `src` automatically after the upload completes

Comment: That's what CollectionFS was doing, only it wasn't checking if the file was written before updating the collection.

Answer (score 1):

For small sized files a way could be to save them as base64 string inside the collection itself. The retrieval is super fast.

For reading the file you can use a drag and drop or select file and then Normal javascript like

```
var reader = new FileReader();
                        var filename = file.name;

                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        reader.onload = function (imgsrc) {
                            var fileVar = imgsrc.target.result;
                            $("#FileUploadingAttachmentNewWay").val(fileVar);
                            $("#FileUploadingAttachmentNameNewWay").val(file.name);

                            $("#FileUploadingAttachmentNewWay").click();
                        }
```

For reading back you need to change if from base64 and put it in a temp  element which you click and download (all in the background). In meteor noticed that if the file size is larger than 4-5mb the collection might get corrupted so we have a limit in the image size.

The code below is for you to assign the base64 in a  and download it. Its not good quality and parts are from tutorials but you will get the point (its from an old test project).

```
function download(strData, strFileName, strMimeType) {
        var D = document,
            A = arguments,
            a = D.createElement("a"),
            d = A[0],
            n = A[1],
            t = A[2] || "application/octet";
        //debugger;
        //build download link:
        a.href = strData.replace("data:;", "data:" + strMimeType + ";").replace("data:text/plain;", "data:" + strMimeType + ";");

        //trying to avoid chrome specific crash (works ok on firefox though) issue 69227 google chrome====>
        //convert to binary in ArrayBuffer this needs change
        var binStr1 = a.href.replace("data:application/octet;base64,", "")
            .replace("data:image/png;base64,", "")
            .replace("data:image/bmp;base64,", "")
            .replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "")
            .replace("data:application/msword;base64,", "")
            .replace("data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,", "")
            .replace("data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,", "")
            .replace("data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,", "");

        var binStr = atob(binStr1);

        var buf = new ArrayBuffer(binStr.length);
        var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
        for (var i = 0; i < view.length; i++)
            view[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);

        var blob = new Blob([view], { 'type': 'application/octet' });
        var URL = webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob)

        a.href = URL;
        //<=================================================================================================

        if (window.MSBlobBuilder) { // IE10
            var bb = new MSBlobBuilder();
            bb.append(strData);
            return navigator.msSaveBlob(bb, strFileName);
        } /* end if(window.MSBlobBuilder) */



        if ('download' in a) { //FF20, CH19
            a.setAttribute("download", n);
            a.innerHTML = "downloading...";
            D.body.appendChild(a);
            setTimeout(function () {
                try {
                    //a.id = "clickToDownload";
                    //$("#clickToDownload").click();
                    var e = D.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                    e.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                    a.dispatchEvent(e);
                    D.body.removeChild(a);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    $.notify("There has been an error trying to download file, please try again or with another browser: " + e.message, "error");
                }
            }, 66);
            return true;
        }; /* end if('download' in a) */



        //do iframe dataURL download: (older W3)
        var f = D.createElement("iframe");
        D.body.appendChild(f);
        f.src = "data:" + (A[2] ? A[2] : "application/octet-stream") + (window.btoa ? ";base64" : "") + "," + (window.btoa ? window.btoa : escape)(strData);
        setTimeout(function () {
            D.body.removeChild(f);
        }, 333);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Indeed but with a little cleaning you will have it ready. The main idea is that for small files you can put them as a string base 64in your database. no need to try finding complicated solutions or add ons etc. A profile picture is very small like 5-10kb and fits perfectly as a base 64 string. You can have it as a separate collection or inside your user collection.