# File upload and download using meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, file-upload, download

I am new to Meteor and web development in general, what I would like to achieve for my meteor web-app is the following:

- A user can click on a button to upload a .zip file (I want this to get stored to my local database as I am building a proof-of-concept run in localhost).
- the file gets associated with a particular object of a Mongodb Collection.
- On the client page associated with that object one can click on a button to download that .zip file.

All the information I found regarding this either deprecated, referring to collectionFS, or too specific/for a niche problem.This has proven more complicated than the issue appears to be!

What i would be looking for is either a tutorial-like guide explaining how to do so or some code snippets that would help get set-up for achieving the mentioned functionality.

**EDIT**

I have managed to upload files using the package [tomi:meteor-upload](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) .
This then creates a `/.uploads` folder where my files are uploaded to.

When I try to download them from the client however using `<a href="/.uploads/myfilename" download target="_blank">Download</a>`, I get that the files downloaded are damaged!

I also tried by uploading them to a `/public` folder than the `/.uploads` folder, but still having the same issue.

This is  seen [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-download-file-from-public-folder/22225), but no solution has been found, even if I chmod 777 my files manually I get the problem!

Thanks!

Comment: I think the way you do this is to expose a server-side route using something like Picker or Iron Router, then your form (which includes the file) would post to that route.  The server-side route would then create the document in the MongoDB collection.  With some JS magic (like jQuery or whatever) you could make this an AJAX call instead of a page reload.

Comment: thanks! wouldn't there be a simpler solution however? I feel that I would have some trouble setting all this system up with the time window I have at  the moment given that I am starting with we development and I haven't set up something similar before.  I managed to find a good package for uploading the files but then I can't download them anymore (edited post)!!

Comment: I am not aware of any simpler solution using Meteor. A typical Meteor app is a SPA (Single Page Application), meaning that the router (Iron Router, Flow Router, etc) sits in the client browser and resolves the URL paths. I believe (although I have never personally proven) that URL patterns not matched in the client get passed to the server. However, unlike a traditional Node.js app, we do not have the req/res objects available. This is where packages like Picker come in...they provide a means to grab the server request and handle them. (cont)

Comment: As for how complicated it would be to set up, that depends on your skill level.  I have used Picker myself, and found it pretty easy to follow the example code and get working. In my case, I was using it to handle REST api calls, and I think from start to finish I had working code in about 20min or so. But, this would only cover the file upload piece.  You will still need to come up with a way to handle the downloads, but I could see using Picker or some similar package for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try busboy https://github.com/mscdex/busboy :

```
this.route('/upload', {
   where: 'server',
   method: 'POST',
   name:'upload',
   onBeforeAction: (function (req, res, next) {
    //busboy code here 
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
       console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ',    encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
       file.on('data', function(data) {
       console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
    });
    file.on('end', function() {
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
    });
   });
   busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, encoding, mimetype) {
    console.log('Field [' + fieldname + ']: value: ' + inspect(val));
   });
   busboy.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Done parsing form!');
    res.writeHead(303, { Connection: 'close', Location: '/' });
    res.end();
    next();
  });
  req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

you can use `file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));`

and the saveTo is the path you where upload, example: `C:/media/` , and try to create ang Path of the link example: `localhost:80/media/image-here.png` use method to store these link in your database, you can use APACHE for File hosting.